# Dealing with `Array.clone()` not showing up via reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, clone

I am writing a library where I want to look for a method with a specific name on a specific class and save that for later. I am doing so via reflection:

```
public static Method findMethod(Class<?> instance_c, String name, Class<?> ... args_cs) {
    return instance_c.getMethod(name, args_cs);
}
```

Now the problem is the following:

```
    Class<?> c = int[].class;
    // int[] i = new int[2].clone();
    System.out.println(findMethod(c, "clone")); // Throws an exception
```

This is documented behaviour:

> *Method java.lang.Class.getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes):*
>
> [snip]
>
> If this Class object represents an array type, then this method does not find the clone() method.

---

Is there a way that I somehow can still use the functionality of `java.lang.reflect.Method` with `Array#clone`? I could imagine a builtin or selfwritten Proxie that lets me keep the functionality of `Method` in this one special case.

If I should further explain what of `Method` I'm using especially, please leave a comment. The goal is to keep as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a class, the array classes are a bit odd and don't have many useful methods of their own relying on helper classes as they don't have any means of extension without changing the language.

The Object.clone() method is available.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
    for(Method m : int[].class.getDeclaredMethods())
        System.out.println(m);
    for(Method m : int[].class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods())
        System.out.println(m);
    Method clone = int[].class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("clone");
    clone.setAccessible(true);
    int[] ints = { 1,2,3 };
    int[] ints2 = (int[]) clone.invoke(ints);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints2));
}
```

prints

```
protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable
public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()
public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode()
public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
public final native void java.lang.Object.notify()
public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()
private static native void java.lang.Object.registerNatives()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Put more simply, you can use `Object.clone()` on any object after making it accessible.